# STM32 Debugger Bug? - Debugger enables PLL for no reason

Tags: stm32, debugging

I'm using a Nucleo F429ZI board and programming it on [System Workbench](https://www.openstm32.org/System%2BWorkbench%2Bfor%2BSTM32). I've been trying to setup a bare-bones project by removing almost all startup code which is created by default, including all clock initialization code.

However, I noticed that the PLLON bit on the RCC_CR register seems to be enabled when I run the code via the debugger, and disabled when I just run the code normally (e.g. by pressing the reset button).

My test code looks like this:

```
int main(void){

  RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOBEN;
  GPIOB->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER7_0;
  GPIOB->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER14_0;

  // This LED only turns on when running the code via the debugger 
  if((RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLON) != 0){
    GPIOB->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_ODR_7;
  }

  // This LED always turns on
  GPIOB->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_ODR_14;

  for(;;);
}
```

Please note that I've edited the startup script such that the main function is the first piece of code that is executed.

It seems that I am not the first one to find this specific bug, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690355/pll-turning-on-when-debugging-on-stm32f767-nucleo) and [here](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/microcontrollers/stm32-clock-gets-modified-when-debugger-is-connected/). Unfortunately, these old threads do not have definite answers as to how to permanently solve this problem besides either forcing reset values by software or doing some weird workaround.

Has anyone found a proper solution yet? Also, given some of the answers in the links above, if this is a problem with openOCD, wouldn't it be relatively easy to submit a fix?

Comment: Does your development environment have any options to script the connect/startup/reset behavior of the debugger it's driving? There may be a default script which makes some assumptions about how the micro should be configured and/or doesn't leave things in the same state it found them after downloading your code.

Comment: Can you please try adding `__DSB();` just after `RCC->AHB1ENR` line and see if anything changes?